# comments validation errors not shown in posts view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on basic blog engine and i have applied validations on comments but when i do a submit it doesn't show errors, instead it shows ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid by rails which is default.

my comments controller is

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
redirect_to @post
end
```

my posts/show view is as below which is working fine for commenting

```
 <%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<p class="comment-notes">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span></p>
<p>
<b><%= f.label :name, "Name *   " %></b><%= f.text_field :name %><br /></p>
<p>
<b><%= f.label :body, "Comment" %></b><%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => 60, :rows => 5 %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Post Comment" %>
</p>
```

can anybody help me to show validation errors on the same posts/show view?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
redirect_to @post
```

with

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
if @comment.errors.any?
  render "posts/show"
else
  redirect_to @post
end
```

unlike create, **create!** will raise error if validations fail

**in posts/show**

```
<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <% if @comment && @comment.errors.any? %>
    <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
   ...
```

Comment: ok it stops raising errors by create method but it still doesn't show validation errors

Comment: I have the same issue, my code looks like yours, but when I submit the empty form, better_errors throws error, please see my topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462349/show-errors-for-comments-if-validation-fails

Comment: Dude, I know it's been a while, but you have saved my life. I couldn't solve the problem that validation did work, but did not pass errors back to post page. I will drink your health. For some reason using .save did not work, had to use create. Rails 5 here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
   if @post.save
     redirect_to @post
   else
     flash[:error] = "Correct errors"
   end
 end
```

In Post model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

 or
```

If you don't want to make as nested model:

```
def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
   if @comment.save
     redirect_to @post
   else
     flash[:error] = "Correct errors"
   end
end
```